# How to pre-install 'nano' using Yocto?

Tags: installation, yocto, yocto-recipe

Starting with an openst-linux Yocto project (but I suppose any other base project, like Poky would do).

I create an image in the following way:

```
DISTRO=openstlinux-weston MACHINE=stm32mp1 source layers/meta-st/scripts/envsetup.sh
bitbake st-image-weston
cd <build>/tmp-glibc/deploy/image/st32mp1/scripts/
./create_sdcard_from_flashlayout.sh ../flashlayout_st-image-weston/optee/FlashLayout_sdcard_stm32mp157f-ev1-optee.tsv
dd ....
```

With this, the SD card boot properly in the device.
After, I would require to add few software, I will take `nano` as an example.

I created a custom image, which I am including at the end of bitbake.conf

```
include ${COREBASE}/../mylayer/conf/layer.conf
```

layers/mylayer/conf/layer.conf:

```
# We have a conf and classes directory, add to BBPATH
curPATH = "${COREBASE}/../mylayer"
BBPATH .= ":${curPATH}"

# We have a recipes-* directories, add to BBFILES
BBFILES += "${curPATH}/*/*.bb \
            ${curPATH}/*.bb \
            ${curPATH}/*/*.bbappend \
            ${curPATH}/*.bb \
            ${curPATH}/*.bbapend"
```

layers/mylayer/image/myimage.bb

```
SUMMARY = "MyLayer weston image"
LICENSE = "Proprietary"

include ${COREBASE}/../meta-st/meta-st-openstlinux/recipes-st/images/st-image-weston.bb
inherit core-image features_check

# let's make sure we have a good image...
REQUIRED_DISTRO_FEATURES = "wayland"

IMAGE_LINGUAS = "en-us"

IMAGE_FEATURES += "\
    splash              \
    package-management  \
    ssh-server-dropbear \
    hwcodecs            \
    tools-profile       \
    eclipse-debug       \
    "

#
# INSTALL addons
#
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += " \
    resize-helper \
    \
    packagegroup-framework-core-base    \
    packagegroup-framework-tools-base   \
    \
    packagegroup-framework-core         \
    packagegroup-framework-tools        \
    \
    packagegroup-framework-core-extra   \
    \
    ${@bb.utils.contains('COMBINED_FEATURES', 'optee', 'packagegroup-optee-core', '', d)} \
    ${@bb.utils.contains('COMBINED_FEATURES', 'optee', 'packagegroup-optee-test', '', d)} \
    \
    ${@bb.utils.contains('COMBINED_FEATURES', 'tpm2', 'packagegroup-security-tpm2', '', d)} \
    \
    packagegroup-st-demo \
    \
    nano\
    "
```

The build is created as explained above, but using:

```
bitbake myimage
```

Which build properly.

But, `nano` is not installed when I boot the SD card.

```
$ nano
 nano: not found
```

**How to pre-install nano into the SD card in Yocto?**

---

Checking that myimage is readed:

When I replace `nano` by any random name, like `randomname`, the build fail. This prove that the layer is getting parsed, and that `nano` is recognized.

Trying to build `nano` individually:

Calling:

```
bitbake nano
```

Succeed.

However, the following line does not:

```
devtool build nano
```

neither:

```
devtool deploy-target -Ss nano root@<ip of my device>
```

Comment: Which branch are you using `warrior`, `dunfell` or any other? What is the `MACHINE` setting in `local.conf`?

Comment: What is MACHINE in local.conf: from my question, it should be stm32mp1, in reality it's stm32mp1-rt because I have a real-time preempt-rt patch in between. I am working with kirkstone branch.

Comment: It seems that moving `CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL` to the parent image st-image-weston.bb fix the issue. I am trying to understand why this variable is override.

Comment: While building (with -v), I can read: `NOTE: myimage-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Installing the following packages: apt pkg nano packagegroup-base-extended ...`

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue was related with how I was creating the SD card:

```
./create_sdcard_from_flashlayout.sh ../flashlayout_st-image-weston/optee/FlashLayout_sdcard_stm32mp157f-ev1-optee.tsv
```

Where, now it should be:

```
./create_sdcard_from_flashlayout.sh ../flashlayout_myimage/optee/FlashLayout_sdcard_stm32mp157f-ev1-optee.tsv
```

Basically, I did not realized that a different folder was created for each image, and that the script needed an update.

Thank you for the help in realizing it.